# Do I have to do anything to make my Electron app "Citrix compatible"?

Tags: javascript, electron, citrix

I have a cross-platform Electron app in beta which I've developed for a client (I'm a contractor) and I just found out today that the app needs to work in a 3rd party's `Citrix` environment. I had no idea what that even was so I have been googling furiously for a few hours. That hasn't helped much so I thought I'd ask here. Sorry for the lame question.

The app is a tool for creating presentations. It accesses the local HD to copy digital assets into a current project folder. It also writes a `JSON` file to the project folder and some preferences to the "Application Support" folder. The app makes two network calls  at startup: one to validate a user entered license key and the other to check for updates. The update is not automatic ("update in place"). The app also supports the copy/paste of text.

That's it. Is this something which will "just work" in a `Citrix` environment or do I need to do some sort of customization? None of the material I've found on `Citrix` describe this sort of basic compatibility (or if it did, I didn't understand it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citrix is a virtual machine, so if you just build your electron app and drop the executable in citrix it should do the job.

We used it in a company i used to work and we rarely(real special cases like really old softwares) had any issues in running any program that would run on windows in citrix.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrix_Virtual_Apps

here is what it actually looks like :

[image]

so you should be fine, no wories

Comment: Thanks. I just spoke to the IT person at the firm using Citrix and it **sounds** like it will work. Fingers crossed . . .